# Is a Muslim allowed to touch a food item for purchase in a kosher bakery?

Tags: halacha, food, islam

Suppose I enter a kosher bakery and want to purchase some food item from the shelves. Can I pick that thing up by my hands for purchase?

My reason is that the laws of Kashrut are very very strict, and I do not want to pollute the kosher items kept in the shelves, but I want to purchase as those things are clean and Halal for muslims to eat or consume, but I also do not want to violate any laws of kosher.

Comment: A really interesting question would be whether a Muslim can touch non-mevushal wine. I'm guessing the practical answer is no, at least al pi gezeira--but what is the theoretical answer?

Comment: @EngineerIshratHussain This is pleasant talk and happiness from a handsome and beautiful person, I am sure. :) Salam.

Comment: Ishrat, the only issue I can think of would be *yayin stam* (wine touched/produced by non-Jews). AFAIK, most schools of Sharia forbid the consumption of alcoholic beverages in the first place, so I can't see why a Muslim would be picking up a bottle of wine (especially at a bakery).

Comment: Beyond generic standards for sanitation (not related to Jewish law) that some people might not like unwashed hands directly touching their food, there's no problem, unless you actually have residue from outside food on your hands. If the food is wrapped then even that wouldn't apply. That's why Jews have no problem buying kosher packaged groceries in a store even though other shoppers and the cashier can and do handle the packages. A kosher bakery may ask that you don't bring outside food in to the bakery, however.

Comment: The reason of OP could also be because, Muslims do have a belief that open food should not be touched by polytheists( with wet hands) or else it has to be washed before consumption. For Muslims, Jews and Christians are ppl of the book so that does not apply to them but the same may not be true the other way around. So what a Muslim wont like for their food the same rule may apply to them as well and so should be careful not to contaminate who may think Muslims to be impure if there is such a concept in Kashrut.  A new Q perhaps: do Jews think Muslims are impure to touch their food?

Comment: Ishrat, I'm aware that your OP did not mention wine. As I said, it shouldn't be an issue at a bakery. FWIW, most bakeries which have accessible food cabinets understand that not all of their patrons are Jewish, so it shouldn't be an issue in any case.

Comment: @David Kenner: Walekum assalam Dear. Thank you for the salam.

Comment: @Noach Mi Frankfurt: Dear Noach, I did not mentioned a Wine in my question, I was asking about other food items, such as cake, pastries, chocolates, breads and buns, or cookies. I know about kosher wine(Mevushal wine made from grapes, and non mevushal wine i.e. unboiled one). Because We muslims can eat from Jewish bakeries but we cannot eat from Christian food supply store without confirming about the pork and it's derivatives in the food item.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is very considerate of a Muslim to care about helping Jewish people protect the laws of kashrut. I assume it is because the Muslim is motivated by fear of Heaven and care for a fellow human being.

There is no known problem in Kosher law which would restrict Muslims from contact with Kosher bakery goods. (to my knowledge)

Thanks for asking.

Comment: The reason of OP could also be because, Muslims do have a belief that open food should not be touched by polytheists( with wet hands) or else it has to be washed before consumption. For Muslims, Jews and Christians are ppl of the book so that does not apply to them but the same may not be true the other way around. So what a Muslim wont like for their food the same rule may apply to them as well and so should be careful not to contaminate who may think Muslims to be impure if there is such a concept in Kashrut.

Comment: @Sarmahdi  Your comment provides extremely helpful context for understanding the possible motivation for the question. Do you think it might be more useful as a comment on the *question*, rather than here as a comment on an *answer*?

Comment: @mwiess I was building on "I assume it is because the Muslim is motivated by fear of Heaven and care for a fellow human being" meaning besides the fear of God and  human care it is also motivated because we believe " Do unto others as you would have them do unto you" so i was answering David's  assumption. but yes looking at Danno's comment it does fit over there as well